# How to export many variables of a simulation result to csv?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, export-to-csv, dymola

I'm trying to export my results from Dymola to excel through a csv file. But I have many results. How can I write them in an array??

I tried to create a for loop but I lack the knowledge on how to type the code.

```
if (time) <= 0 then
   Modelica.Utilities.Files.removeFile("tube_0.02"+".csv");
   Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("temps," +
      "delta_fr1,"+
      "delta_fr2,"+
      "delta_fr3,",
    "tube_0.02"+".csv");
 else

 Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print(String(time) +
   "," + String(   my_code_tube1[1].delta_fr)+
   "," + String(   my_code_tube1[2].delta_fr)+
   "," + String(   my_code_tube1[3].delta_fr),
     "tube_0.02"+".csv");

 end if;
```

Instead of having to write delta_fr1, delta_fr2...  and then my_code_tube1[1].delta_fr, my_code_tube1[2].delta_fr.... I need to create a for loop because I will have almost 1500 variable to export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to write the results to a csv file during simulation comes with some troubles in Modelica:

- For which time steps do you want to write the result? Using the solver step size is not possible. 
  But we can define a periodic output using the `sample()` function
- Calling print is quite expensive. You don't want to do that too many times while your simulation runs
- The print function always adds a newline after every call. That requires us to write every line at once (but due to the performance limits mentioned before we should write as much text as possible at once anyhow).
  Unfortunately, the default maximum string size of Dymola is quite small, limited on 500. 
  You have to ensure that the current Dymola instance is using an appropriate large value by setting e.g. `Advanced.MaxStringLength = 50000`.

With these things in mind, we could come up with a code like below:

```
model SO_print_for
  My_code_tube my_code_tube1[1500];

protected 
  String line;
  String f="tube_0.02" + ".csv";

  model My_code_tube
    Real delta_fr=1;
  end My_code_tube;

initial algorithm 
  line := "temps";
  for i in 1:size(my_code_tube1,1) loop
    line := line + ", delta_fr" + String(i);
  end for;
  Modelica.Utilities.Files.removeFile(f);
  Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print(line, f);

algorithm 
  when sample(0, 0.1) then
    line := String(time);
    for i in 1:size(my_code_tube1,1) loop
      line := line + ", "+String(my_code_tube1[i].delta_fr);
    end for;
    Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print(line, f);
  end when;

end SO_print_for;
```

The code works, but it will slow down your simulation, as many time events are generated (from the `sample()` function).

Instead of writing a csv during the simulation, you should consider one of the following ways to convert the result file after the simulation has finished:

- Use Export Result in the Dymola variable browser to export all or only the plotted variables into csv. This must be done manually after every simulation and can not be scrippted
- Use the function `DataFiles.convertMATtoCSV`. The following two lines of code will extract 1500 `delta_fr` variables from the .mat result file

```
    vars = {"my_code_tube1["+String(i)+"].delta_fr" for i in 1:1500}
    DataFiles.convertMATtoCSV("your-model.mat", vars, "out.csv")
```

- Use Matlab, Octave or FreeMat to open the .mat result file and convert it to a file format which Excel understands.
  Dymola provides `dymload.m` to import .mat result files into Matlab. See the User manual volume 1 of Dymola for details
- Use python to convert the results to a csv file, e.g. by using the package [DyMat](https://www.j-raedler.de/projects/dymat/) or [SDF-Python](https://github.com/ScientificDataFormat/SDF-Python), which can both be used to read the result files

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I add the time variable in the print function. I will try your way, thank you.

Comment: Actually there are two ways of scripting the CSV-export from Dymola. One involves a combination of readTrajectory (or similarly) and DataFiles.writeCSVmatrix and the other is $ %Dymola%\bin\alist -e var1 dsres.mat res.csv

Comment: Thanks Hans. I have included the DataFiles variant. alist might not be a good option for so many variables.